# How can I merge the last elements of an Array that fits a curve?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to make a base for a hard surface model I'm working on using mostly modifiers, and I was hoping I could create a closed "conic" shape out of a simple plane by using an Array modifier and a Deform Curve modifier. But I can't get the first and last elements to merge properly. The best I can do is modify the scale of both curve and mesh until I cant get them close enough, but then I end up with another element overlapping the first one, causing artifacts on rendering, such as: [image]

[image]

Is there any way to get the last merge with one of the other Fit Types of the array, or some other fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first-last merge is being requested before the array is deformed: at that stage the first and last are nowhere near each other..

It may not be ideal for you, but in this case you could do the rotation *in* the array, by using an object-offset, target: say an empty, rotated by (360/sides) in Z. Then the merge works.

[image]

This example has a bevel-by-angle modifier after the array.

Edit: Since this answer, the *Weld* modifier has become available, and can be used to stitch vertices together in this, and other situations.

Comment: Thanks, this seem to work! The curve had some interesting degree of control of with the Mean Radius and Tilt properties, too bad it doesn't work for this purpose though.